# Quickstep in Outlook 2013 Gmail IMAP account doesn't execute "mark as read" instruction

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am using Office 2013, and I have a Gmail account set up via IMAP.  I have created an "Archive" quickstep in Outlook with 2 instructions:

1. mark item as read
2. move to folder "All Mail"

If I execute this quickstep on a message that is unread, the message is moved but not marked as read.  Once my All Mail folder syncs, the newly moved message shows up as unread in the All Mail folder.  For some reason, Gmail never thinks that the message is read.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Apparently Outlook always had this problem when combining the actions of moving items and Mark as Read. Try maybe to do it in the opposite order. Or divide it into two Quickstep actions.